# Prevent Text Box Value Update if Invalid Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a handler for several text boxes (`<input type="text">`) on my form.

```
$(popUp).on('change', 'input', function (e) {
}
```

All values must be numeric and I call `$.isNumeric($(this).val())` to ensure that the new value complies.

If the value is not numeric, however, I will display a message. But I would also like to restore the text box value to its original value to ensure the form data remains valid.

Is there any automated way to prevent the text box value from being updated?

Comment: You can keep previous value in a hidden field.

Comment: @AlexChar: Sure but I have quite a few of them. Since browsers don't seem to signal the change event until the user leaves the control, I just wondered if there was a way to prevent that final event from completing.

Comment: I suppose the best way would be to prevent the user from typing a non-numeric character in the first place!

Comment: I think, you can first store the existing value (valid or empty) in a temp variable and then after if the  value is changed and it is invalid, put the temp value back in the textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this approach for reverting to initial value if the new value is numeric:

```
$(popUp).on('change', 'input', function (e) {
    if (!$.isNumeric(this.value)) {
        this.value = $(this).attr('value');
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('value', this.value);
    }
});
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/pLok67xh/

Another option could be to block non-numeric input all together, not sure if you need this though.

Comment: This is very interesting. I wonder if this is documented and/or reliable across browsers.

Comment: Yes, of course. Nothing really surprising here though. This effect is due to the difference between attributes and properties. Value attribute is equivalent to default input value, so even when you change property value, attribute keeps its original value.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the Notes section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute#Notes).

Comment: Thanks. Just to further clarify, if I initialize the value to "1", and the user updates it to "2", and then the user updates it to "a" and I use the technique above, it will revert to "1" and not "2", is that correct? In other words, the original value here always refers to the value when the element was first created? I need to think this through but definitely find this interesting.

Comment: If after value has changed to "2" value attribute also updates to "2", then "2" will become a new default value. Experiment with demo I provided.

Comment: Although a good approach is to simply filter input to ensure it is valid, this is more of the direction I was wanting to go, and I think more accurately answers what I was asking.

Answer (score 3):

as I said in the comments, if you prevent the user from typing any non-numeric character in the first place, all the problems are solved:

```
$('input:text').keydown(function( e ) {    
    if(!/([\d ,\$])+/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which)))
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: This is a valid approach. But if the user wants to include commas or a currency symbol, my preference is to let them and then just strip it off when I process the final result. This requires that I strip off those characters and, if I don't have anything left, it would be nice to restore the original value.

Comment: check the regex again, this will let the user to use space, comma and dollar sign as well as digits, you can add more signs or characters if needed!

Comment: Again, it's a valid approach, one that I had considered. But our app supports many different currency symbols and it might be difficult to ensure all of them are covered. I think my preference here is not to do this.

Answer (score 2):

you can add keydown event.

```
    $(popUp).on('keydown', 'input', function (e) {
         var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
         if unicode >= 48 && unicode <= 57 {
             return true;
         }
         else{
              return false;
         }
    });
```